# Preserve DateTimeOffset in Date String after UTC to TimeZoneInfo Date Conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

Given the following UTC date string: "2020-10-10T12:00:00"

When converting to string, why do I loose the datetime offset, despite specifying it in the format?

```
string parseString = "2020-10-10T12:00:00";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(parseString, "s", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate))
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific/Honolulu");

    DateTime atUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    DateTimeOffset dateAtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(atUtc, timeZoneInfo);
    Console.WriteLine(dateAtTimeZone.ToString("O"));
    Console.WriteLine(dateAtTimeZone.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK"));
}
```

Why do I get back the following: `2020-10-10T02:00:00.0000000+13:00`

Instead of: `2020-10-10T02:00:00.0000000-10:00`

Comment: Then don't use a `DateTime` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTime_System_DateTimeOffset_System_TimeZoneInfo_).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - are you saying that I have to manually specify the offset? That is what I got from your link. 

I presumed if you converted a DateTime object using a timezone, it would intrinsically hold some localisation / offset information and I could apply the following formats for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier

Comment: @nealsu "it would intrinsically hold some localisation / offset information" No it doesn't. That's the job of `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: DateTime is only well defined for UTC & this machine's timezone. Too many method will do something surprising if the Kind is unspecified. IMHO only use it for storing UTC. As soon as you want "local" or "user" time values, use DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @Sweeper - thanks for the response, I now understand that and have updated my answer. Could you now explain why the actual datetime string format is still not as expected? It appears to be using the machines offset not the specified timezone.

Comment: Because `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` is still operating on `DateTime`s. You didn't really change anything. You've just converted the incorrect result from before to an `DateTimeOffset`. You should also make `atUtc` a `DateTimeOffset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netcore-3.1) that takes 2 parameters - one that takes a `DateTime` and returns a `DateTime`, and one that takes an `DateTimeOffset` and returns a `DateTimeOffset`. Right now, you are calling the one that takes a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime atUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset dateAtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(atUtc, timeZoneInfo); // atUtc is a DateTime here!
```

The fact that you are assigning the result to `DateTimeOffset` doesn't matter, because the return value type does not participate in overload resolution.

The overload that takes a `DateTime` just changes the date and time parts of the `DateTime` passed in, since timezone/offset information is not a part of `DateTime`s. When you convert it to `DateTimeOffset`, your local offset is added to it during the conversion, and that is what gets printed.

What you should be calling is the overload that takes an `DateTimeOffset`. Because it takes a `DateTimeOffset`, it is able to change the *offset* part of the `DateTimeOffset` as well as the date and time parts, to the desired values. You need to declare `atUtc` as `DateTimeOffset` too:

```
DateTimeOffset atUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeOffset dateAtTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(atUtc, timeZoneInfo);
```

Or better, use `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact` in the first place!